# Deducing if the series converges.

Tags: calculus

$$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{}^{} \dfrac{1}{k(ln(k)^2)}$$

Integral test

$$\int_{} \frac {1}{u^2} du = \int  u^{-2} du = \frac {-1}{u} = \frac{-1}{\ln k} +c$$

Comment: Are you sure that it converges to zero? What does $1/\ln(1)$ equal?

Comment: If the integral were zero then the infinite sum would have to be zero too, which is clearly not true.

Comment: In the original problem this might have been my fault but the sigma notation was blank. No upper or lowerbound; just Σ

Comment: If its just a $\Sigma$ with no limits I think its fair to assume its an infinite series. But the starting point is more than likely no less than $k=2$. Otherwise the ratio is obviously undefined at the first term, then so too would the sum be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the integral test as you suggested

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k \ln^2k} < \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\ln^2x} dx = \frac{1}{\ln (2)}$$

where $\int \frac{1}{x \ln^2x} dx = - \frac{1}{\ln x}  + C$

Comment: The answer is converges I presume.

Comment: That's correct!

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the [Cauchy Condensation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

See that the terms of the sequence are non negative and decreasing, so $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k(\ln^2 k)}$ converges if and only if $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^k}{2^k(\ln^2 2^k)} = \dfrac{1}{\ln^2 2}\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^2}$ converges (which is true).

Since, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} \le \displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}\right) = 1$ (telescopes).